# How to filter data using stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to redo the functionality using Stream API, but I can't figure out how I can filter user names by date in the same way, given that both dates can be null. Can anyone help me out?

```
public int getNumberOfUsers(Date after, Date before) {
    Set<String> uniqUsers = new HashSet<>();
    for (LogRecord rec : logRecords) {
        if ((after == null || rec.date.getTime() >= after.getTime()) &&
                (before == null || rec.date.getTime() <= before.getTime())) {
            uniqUsers.add(rec.user);
        }
    }
    return uniqUsers.size();
}
```

Comment: You can just put the code which you have in your `if` condition inside the body of the lambda in the filter of your stream.

Comment: I believe condition needs to be modified, otherwise you may get a NPE.
`(after != null && rec.date.getTime() >= after.getTime()) &&
                    (before != null && rec.date.getTime() <= before.getTime())`

Comment: Are you using or trying to use the API class `LogRecord`? If not, please show your `LogRecord` class and any other required classes.  And if you just want a count, why use a `List<String>`?  Just initialize an `int to 0` increment as required.  Then return the value.

Answer (score -1):

```
uniqUsers = logRecords.stream().filter(rec -> (after != null && rec.date.getTime() >= after.getTime()) &&
                (before != null && rec.date.getTime() <= before.getTime())).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
logRecords.stream()
  .filter( rec -> 
      (after == null || rec.date.getTime() >= after.getTime()) && 
      (before == null || rec.date.getTime() <= before.getTime())
.distinct().count()
```

First, it filters the your records by condition, which I haven't touched.
Then, it only returns distinct elements, which is equivalent to adding to Set.
Lastly, it returns the resulting count.

`after` and `before` variables can be used as is since they are "captured" by the closure.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Test {
    private List<LogRecord> logRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getNumberOfUsers(DateRange dateRange) {
        return (int)logRecords.stream()
            .filter(rec -> isMatch(dateRange, rec))
            .map(LogRecord::getUser)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .distinct()
            .count();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Date date = new Date();
        test.logRecords.add(new LogRecord("user1", date));
        test.logRecords.add(new LogRecord("user2", date));

        int numberOfUsers = test.getNumberOfUsers(new DateRange(date, null));
        System.out.println(numberOfUsers == 2);
    }

    private boolean isMatch(DateRange dateRange, LogRecord rec) {
        return dateRange.isMatch(rec.getDate());
    }

    static class DateRange {
        private final Date after;
        private final Date before;

        public DateRange(Date before, Date after) {
            this.after = after;
            this.before = before;
        }

        public Date getAfter() {
            return after;
        }

        public Date getBefore() {
            return before;
        }

        boolean isMatch(Date date) {
            return (getAfter() == null || date.compareTo(getAfter()) >= 0 &&
                (getBefore() == null || date.compareTo(getBefore()) <= 0));
        }
    }


    static class LogRecord {
        private String user;
        private Date date;

        public LogRecord(String user, Date date) {
            this.user = user;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope these codes will help you.